# How to change a commercial device configuration?

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-failure

We sell **ReSound TV Streamers**, which is an interface between a Hearing Aid and a TV. So a Hearing Aid user can listen to the TV directly in their hearing aid.

[image]

**Problem:**
This device shutsdown in 10 minutes if its not streaming anything, but, for a specific patient, we need it to stay on forever, it does not matter if it streaming or not.

I wanna know if there is any chance I can enter this device properties through software (it is an USB device) and find where this information in programmed.

I'm feeling the only way to approach this on going "behind the curtains" and try programming this myself. Can someone give me the first steps to this? How can I search for this on Google?

*[EDIT] After a few minutes of research, I found that this may be a firmware related problem. Maybe I need to get inside this device firmware? How?*

**Extra info:**

1. It is an USB device (only used to connect to computer)
2. We tried reaching our supplier (ReSound) and they said they are not going to change this for us.
3. In instructions manual there is nothing related to this
4. There is a ReSound software which I can update this product
5. In this software there is no configuration to where I can change this 10 minutes shutdown property

Comment: The only way you can program it yourself is if the manufacturers give you all their source code. This is somewhat unlikely

Comment: @Mokubai They will not give me the source code because of compliance, which is a shame. Thank you for you contribution. Will try another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no device setting to control this directly and the manufacturer won't help you then I'm afraid you are pretty much stuck.  You would need to flash the firmware (which is what step 4 is doing) with a version that includes the option to control the shutdown timer which is something that the manufacturer would need to provide.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Since changing the firmware is not an option, we are trying to build a beep generator that generates a beep every 10 minutes to stimulate the product audio signal so it does not shuts off. We are using an Arduino for it. So far, the most elegant solution we found.

Comment: Nice, hope that works for you!  Just out of curiosity, are you mixing that into the audio signal from the TV?

Comment: Yes, so the TV signal goes TrueBypass through the Arduino, but if the Arduino generates a sound, the signal goes through the ReSound Streamer as well, in the same input as the TV.